# Will MSE-based estimator generate symmetric residuals if the error has got symmetric support (not distribution)?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distributions, mse, symmetry

This question is more specific than :[my old question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/545073/will-quadratic-based-estimation-not-necessarily-mse-always-generate-a-symmetri)

Take follow regression model:

$y=f(x)+e$

Where $e\sim D$ with a such symmetric support $A=(-a,a)$, not symmetric distribution. Now given a data set $\{x_i,y_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ and a estimator $g(.,\mathbf{\beta})$ to $f$.

Will I always get symmetric residuals if:

$\beta=argmin_{\beta}(\sum_{i=1}^{N}(g(x_i,\beta)-y_i)^2)$

I've simulated a regression problem where $y=x^2+e$ with $e$ having the follow distribution:

$f(e)=\frac{1}{exp(1)-exp(-1)}exp(e) I(e)_{\{-1,1\}}$

That is not symmetric at all:

[image]

But using random forest with MSE impurity to train $\{x_i,y_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ I got these residuals:

[image]

Where are clearly symmetric. I think it'll always happen but I'm not able to proof it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**STILL NO**

I have a similar argument as I gave in your previous question. Let's do the same model but with an error term that is an asymmetric beta distribution that is shifted to have support on $[-0.5, 0.5]$. I then take this a step further and multiply by a scaling factor to expand the support to $[-50, 50]$. I encourage readers to play with the `a`, `b`, and `m` values to see what happens.

```
set.seed(2021)
N <- 10000
a <- 1
b <- 3
m <- 100
x <- seq(0, 10, 10/(N - 1))
e <- rbeta(N, a, b) - 0.5 # subtract 0.5 so support is [-0.5, 0.5], not [0, 1]
e <- m * e # Multiply by m to stretch or compress the support to [-m/2, m/2]
y <- x + e
plot(x, y)
L <- lm(y ~ x)
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
hist(resid(L))
hist(e)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

The empirical range of my `e` values is $-49.99677$ to $45.6901$, so the support looks pretty symmetric about $0$ (which we expect from the construction). However, neither the residuals nor the error term are symmetric, as the histograms below show.

[image]

Comment: Please see the hist of your genereted error this hasn't got symmetric interval that is $f(e)$ doesn't have non-null probability in whole interval $(-a,a)$. It seems there is $(-50,-10-ish)$ as support density on it, I'd argue your sample is little sized to stand for but that's not. Look through $length(e[e>-10])/N$ you will get in your hands a null probability when that should get you a positive probability beacause the sup would must be at $(-50,50)$.

Comment: The residuals might not have an error term with symmetric support, but the error term does.

Comment: The error should have symmetric support but that doesn't happen. Please see the error's histogram (not residuals) and be careful using qqplot to evaluate symmetry it actually does normality

Comment: I actually think the example I gave last night works (maybe not, but I think so), but it might have been too extreme to demonstrate what I wanted to show. The new simulation should be quite emphatic.

Comment: Ok I think it worked enough xD, thank you.